# .obj view files with interaction

Tags: android, surfaceview, .obj

I'm looking for an android component that loads .obj files and has rotation, zoom and zoom interaction.
I need this component to be placed on a camera preview (eg, surfaceview) and can crash a photo by merge the .obj viewer component with the camera preview.
Has anyone else found a solution to these cases? Can you give me some links and examples?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

This is the base project!
From it I'm putting the camera to take the photo along with the 3d object. However, the project is well underway to load and interact with 3d objects.
https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer

Comment: This project is has lots of dependencies. It's really hard to get libraries from this project.